# Getting 401 with reason youtubeSignupRequired

Tags: youtube-api

Getting error while uploading video via API on a channel which was working properly before, and started to get this error after a transfer of the youtube channel was initiated.

Tried to re-authenticate from initial owner's account and then also from the account to which we requested to be transferred to and still getting this error which seems to be an unexpected behaviour

```
{
  code: 401,
  errors: [
    {
      message: 'Unauthorized',
      domain: 'youtube.header',
      reason: 'youtubeSignupRequired',
      location: 'Authorization',
      locationType: 'header'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Any update about this?